# How to resize the widget that hold a QTableView?

Tags: pyqt4, qtableview

I have a QTableView inside a layout itself inside a Widget.
How I can set the Widget size after the call of tableView.resizeColumnsToContents() in order to have the same size of the table (and does not need a scrollbar )
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand properly what you want is to adjust the horizontal size of the container widget to the size of the table *contents* (which is not necessarily the table size). The following method works for me with a small table of 20 rows and 3 columns:

- ask the table model for the total number of columns (it should be returned by your implementation of the `columnCount` method)
- ask the view for the width of every column using the `columnWidth` method and compute the total width of the columns
- finally resize your container widget taking into account the total width of columns, the width of the table vertical header and the autoscroll margin

So the code would look like:

```
my_table_view.resizeColumnsToContents()
w = 0
for c in range(my_table_model.columnCount()):
    w = w + my_table_view.columnWidth(c)
container_widget.resize(w + my_table_view.verticalHeader().width() + my_table_view.autoScrollMargin()*1.5, container_widget.size().height())
```

As I said, I'm assuming that you want to resize your widget horizontally.

Comment: You understood perfectly my need! I will try this solution!